# Eusocial Humanoids?

Tags: evolution, fantasy-races, humanoid, hive

How could a humanoid race and/or a human subspecies develop eusocial behavior? It's more common in insects like bees, but the naked mole rat is a eusocial mammal, so it's possible, any thoughts on the how/why of such a development?

Answer (score 5):

## We are already fairly Euosocial

[A quick search on wikipedia's Eusociality page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eusociality) would tell you that humans have been refered to as a species of eusocial ape.

Note that the requirements of Eusociality are simply:

- Reproductive division of labor (with or without sterile castes)
- Overlapping generations
- Cooperative care of young

Humans do all of these things.

If you look at our behaviour more closely as a society you'll see it come through.

- Overlapping generations: Large families living together, and if you think about it more, we've got "generation X", "millenials", etc etc.
- Cooperative care of young: Day cares, baby sitters, etc etc.
- Reproductive division of labor: It's harder to draw comparison here since humans don't lay eggs, but what it really boils down to is "division of labor" which we clearly participate in; every single job opening is a type of division of labor.

Comment: Well, how would things go a step further then?

Comment: @TheLiteraryLord in some ways we're pulling *back* from it. Reintroduce castes and/or classes, repurpose the older folk as community child care, and abolish things like nursing homes, making the family unit more responsible for the extended family than a normal atomic family unit generally allows. All these things would be considered by most enlightened societies as a retrograde step but if there was a compelling reason to do it (like the ageing population issue) that may change. Not the castes, but certainly a more active role in childraising for the elderly at least.

Comment: I meant more in an evolutionary sense.

Answer (score 0):

Genetic engineering gone savage? The queen started as a way for the geneticist to be their own lab and petri dish, monitoring every nutrient and hormone for every experiment. Maybe then there's a natural disaster and they start making specialized people just to survive and then to build fortresses and empires. Thanks for the idea by the way, very inspiring.