# Factors Promoting Eusociality?

Tags: evolution, hive

What scenarios would promote a species, especially a mammalian one, to evolve to be more eusocial? What kind of advantages would a eusocial species have over a non-eusocial species?

Comment: Can you explain a bit how this is different from [your previous question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/116191/627)?

Comment: This is more general than just humanoids. Also, my previous question was never really answered to my satisfaction.

Comment: What research have you done on the topic? I was able to answer your last question by taking 2 minutes to skim Wikipedia and using some common sense.

Comment: The same things that promote any form of evolution. Also you really need to respond to HDE226868's point by editing the question to explain what you need that you didn't get from Aify last time around, otherwise this isn't a question that can be usefully answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is kind of the way that wolves could potentially be evolving.  If you think about how the Alpha Male gets to mate with the Alpha Female if you pushed it to the extreme, the rest of the pack may become celibate so that only the strongest get to mate. Perhaps given enough time this leads to a more colonial life style, similar to bees.

The biggest hurdle to this idea is that a single female can only produce and care for so many children per litter. You'd need to figure out a way to have more rapid breading cycles and have Betas aid her in caring for the children.  Perhaps there is only a few males born per generation and they fight for dominance.

The second hurdle is to prevent inbreeding.  The males could fight an other pack's males to mate with their Alpha Female (queen). The winner gets to mate and the losers are eaten or cast out. (more likely eaten so that they don't have to compete with them for food)  Then all the pack females are made to lactate by the pheromones that the Alpha Female produces when she is pregnant.  This would allow them to care for much larger litters and share the burden across the pack.  The Alpha female would have to have a much larger abdomen to allow for larger litters than modern day wolves.  She'd likely look more elongated or barrel shaped.

Something like that...